# hooking up the data model in ReactJS - syntax

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking off of the reactjs tutorial on how to build a comment box with react. I get that we are mapping over data, but I cant understand this syntax and part of the code. Would be really helpful if you could explain exactly what is going on here. Specifically, why is props author={comment.author} within the Comment element tag itself and {comment.text} is not.

```
<Comment author={comment.author}>
    {comment.text}
</Comment>
```

---

Context:

```
var data = [
  {author: "Pete Hunt", text: "This is one comment"},
  {author: "Jordan Walke", text: "This is *another* comment"}
];

var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function (comment) {
  return (
    <Comment author={comment.author}>
      {comment.text}
    </Comment>
  );
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, we should understand, how `Comment` is defined. From the ReactJS tutorial:

```
var Comment = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="comment">
        <h2 className="commentAuthor">
          {this.props.author}
        </h2>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

The call to `React.createClass` defines new component, which could be rendered in the following way:

```
<Comment author="Pete Hunt">This is one comment</Comment>

<!-- Will be transformed into -->

<div className="comment">
  <h2 className="commentAuthor">
    Pete Hunt
  </h2>
    This is one comment
</div>
```

As you can see, `{this.props.author}` has been replaced with `Pete Hunt`, defined as `author` property of `Comment` component, and `{this.pros.children}` - with `Comment`'s content (just `This is one comment` in this case).

Now we could move to `CommentList` declaration. Your `commentNodes` function is a part of this component, so, I'll show full definition:

```
var CommentList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function (comment) {
      return (
        <Comment author={comment.author}>
          {comment.text}
        </Comment>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="commentList">
        {commentNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Here you can see `render` function, defined in terms of `commentNotes` (`<div className="commentList"> {commentNodes} </div>`). So, what does `commentNodes` do?

It transforms each `comment` object into `Comment` component. Suppose, we have `this.props.data` defined as:

```
var data = [
  {author: "Pete Hunt", text: "This is one comment"},
  {author: "Jordan Walke", text: "This is *another* comment"}
];
```

Thus, calling `commentNodes` will create the following components:

```
<Comment author="Pete Hunt">This is one comment</Comment>
<Comment author="Jordan Walke">This is *another* comment</Comment>
```

That will be rendered as:

```
<div className="comment">
  <h2 className="commentAuthor">
    Pete Hunt
  </h2>
    This is one comment
</div>
<div className="comment">
  <h2 className="commentAuthor">
    Jordan Walke
  </h2>
    This is *another* comment
</div>
```

---

**UPD**

> Specifically, why is props author={comment.author} within the Comment
>   element tag itself and {comment.text} is not.

This is pretty simple - by design. You could rewrite `Comment` component in the following way:

```
var Comment = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="comment">
        <h2 className="commentAuthor">
          {this.props.author}
        </h2>
        {this.props.content}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

And rewrite `CommentList` as:

```
var CommentList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function (comment) {
      return (
        <Comment author={comment.author} content={comment.text} />
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="commentList">
        {commentNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Note also, passing comment text as `{this.props.children}` allows you to create `Comment` with nested elements, not only with text.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I guess my question was more about why author={comment.author} is within the Comment element tag itself and {comment.text} is not. Understanding that would be helpful.

Comment: @chiuchiu, this is, so called, "by design". I have updated the post.

Comment: @chiuchiu, You are always welcome. Please, mark it as answer (just under the rate of the post), this will help people with same question.